# Download file by its URL in Angular

Tags: angular, file, download

How can I download a file if I have its URL? Always open the file and shows its text.
Code below doesn't work :(

I get the URL by consuming an API. I don't have the chance to receive in other way.

```
<a href="https://dominio.com/report.txt" download="reporte.txt" target="_blank">Descargar</a>
```

Comment: *Code below doesn't work*. What happens?

Comment: @SwissCodeMen Open a new tab and display the text. How could I avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just need to define the download tag like this below,

```
<a href="https://dominio.com/report.txt" download="reporte.txt">
<strong>Descargar</strong>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the url has given below its downloaded correctly.

```html
<a href="/dominio.com/report.txt" download="reporte.txt" target="_blank">Descargar</a>
```

Comment: for some reason this show the legend "Can't download: There's not any file".

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver package. Please make sure your url responds with blob response headers.

```
Content-Type: 'application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8'
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.jpg"; filename*="filename.jpg"
Content-Length: <size in bytes>
```